# Best solution for mobile app <-> Rails app authorization/authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, mobile, authorization

I'm current designing a Rails application that uses a form for user login, then persists session information in a cookie. However, I plan on a bulk of the interaction with the Rails application to be via a mobile app instead of a web browser.

What is the best way to accomplish user auth? I suppose I could save a cookie with my app. Or perhaps authenticate with every request. Perhaps there's a gem for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the **Devise** gem.

It's REALLY good, supported by people that really know about Rails, and I guess I could say it's become the "industry standard" for these matters.

[Devise on GitHub](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: Devise is probably a good solution, however even Devise's documentation suggests rolling your own to learn the ropes. while your suggestion is a good one and I'll probably use it in the future, I can't accept that as the answer... But I will upvote it :)

Comment: :) yep, agreed. I wouldn't only use a homemade solution in a "real" app, unless you're already really well versed in this field. Authentication has its many problems, and the real solution has dealt with mostly all of them during the time they're on air. But go ahead and build your own, you'll learn a lot from that :)